# Will drinking too much beetroot juice cause gynecomastia?

Tags: diet, testosterone, estrogen, gynecomastia-man-boobs

Searching online for "beets testosterone" there are sources that state that [beets boost testosterone levels](https://longevity.technology/lifestyle/add-these-juices-to-your-diet-today-to-boost-testosterone/).
e.g.

> The vitamin and antioxidant content of beetroot is high. It is also
> rich in dietary nitrates, which boost testosterone levels

Searching online for "beets gynecomastia" there are sources that state that [beets increase estrogen levels](https://synergywellnesscenter.com/blog/is-your-diet-causing-gynecomastia/) (hence men should avoid beets). E.g.

> Beetroots: Beetroots contain high estrogen levels, which could cause
> your testosterone levels to decrease. Try to avoid this food to
> balance your hormones.

Also from an [article](https://www.gynecomastia-specialist.com/could-your-diet-cause-gynecomastia/) that says is written from a doctor but there are no references mentioned

> The top foods that cause man breasts are soy products, beetroot, ....

.

If beets do cause gynecomastia that would mean that regardless of what they do to testosterone levels, they should increase estrogen abnormally high.

What is the source of this contradiction?
What do reputable medical sources report on this?

Comment: Hi Alexandra, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are expected to show prior research. It sounds like you've done quite a bit. Unfortunately, we can't refute things like "I have heard that beets may contribute to the development of male breasts." Instead, please [edit] your post to **quote** and link to the sources that are causing the confusion.

Comment: @IanCampbell: I updated the post

Comment: @smith Thank you for trying to improve the post. I think your edit would make the question on topic, but I'm worried that your edit may not maintain the initial intent of the question author. While edits are welcome, they should always leave the post in a state that is consistent with the original intent of the question. I will leave the edit pending in case the question author comes along and approves it. Alternatively, you could ask a totally separate question.

Comment: @IanCampbell: ok thank you